# Ribbon diagram in amcharts4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Is there any way to build chart like this:

[image]

Sankey diagram is not quite same thing, it`s more like stacked column chart with sorting each column, but is there any way to connect stacks?

Comment: Did you find any?